# Pandas mean for certain columns (binary values) based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

Suppose we have something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,13], [1,0,1,14], [1,1,0,12], [1,0,0,15]], columns = ["A", "B" , "C", "p"])
```

A, B, C have binary values and I want to compute mean of p for each column, but for each group (1 and 0) separately.

For one column I use

```
df.groupby('A')['p'].mean()
```

But how to compute mean for columns ABC at once?

Comment: How should looks expected output?

Comment: perfect would be:  two columns 0 and 1 and  3 rows A, B, C

Comment: Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael perfect! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot first, aggregate `mean` and last add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('p').groupby(['variable', 'value'])['p'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('p').pivot_table(index='variable', columns='value', values='p', fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df1)
value             0          1
variable                      
A         13.000000  13.666667
B         14.500000  12.500000
C         13.333333  14.000000
```